# Jenkins - Pipeline (Amazon EC2 Container Service Plugin)

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ecs

I just started to use Jenkins and Pipeline, and I'm using it with Jenkins Amazon EC2 Container Service Plugin.

Everything works fine so far, I declared the agent that I need to use it for my build, it starts the docker image to make a build and finish it once the task is done.

However, I thought I would be able to run multiple tasks at the same time (that for each task, it would run a new docker service), but looks like only one slave is only available.

For example, if my slave is currently doing something, the next task will wait with the following message : "Waiting for next available executor on Jenkins-Slave-12cbf90f1ed9"

I setup my pipeline like that :

```
#!groovy
pipeline {
agent { label 'maven'}
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            sh 'mvn clean install'
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something that I didn't corretly setup, or this is how is it supposed to work ?

Comment: shouldn't there be some `agent { docker blabla }`?

Comment: Well I'm not sure, I think this is when you want to run a slave docker inside your master server ? In my case, I'm running my master Jenkins as a task on Amazon EC2 Container Service already. Then the Amazon EC2 Container Service Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Container+Service+Plugin) is taking care of spawning new docker instance on the cluster to execute the pipeline.

Comment: Ah, okay, didn't know that this hooks into slave provisioning like this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (edit the cluster/image/taskRoleArn to match your freestyle job):

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        ecsNode([cluster: 'DEV',
            image: 'dwi',
            memory: '1.0',
            taskRoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/JENKINS_ROLE']) {
          sh 'echo hello world'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```